# Postgresql Syntax error at or near "where"

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

I am getting the error

> syntax error at or near "where" LINE 5: where zip in (select zipcode
>   from zips where city = 'Sacra

when I try to run this code.

```
update listings
set price = CASE WHEN (listings.price IS NOT NULL) THEN (price * 
(((100+(select price_change from zips where zips.zipcode=listings.zip))/100)))
where zip in (select zipcode from zips where city = 'Sacramento');
```

Does anybody see any easy to fix errors? or did I come up with some garbage code?

Comment: You don't need the case, as you have no `else` part.  Just add `price is not null` to your where clause and you can get rid of the whole `CASE` and make the update even more efficient.

Comment: just see the updated answer @a_horse_with_no_name suggestion is added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an **end** keyword just before **where** clause

```
update listings
set price = CASE WHEN (listings.price IS NOT NULL) THEN (price * 
(((100+(select price_change from zips where zips.zipcode=listings.zip))/100))) END
where zip in (select zipcode from zips where city = 'Sacramento');
```

---

As per @a_horse_with_no_name's Comment

```
update listings 
set price = (price * (((100+(select price_change from zips where zips.zipcode=listings.zip))/100))) 
where zip in (select zipcode from zips where city = 'Sacramento') and listings.price IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

An [SQL `CASE` expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) needs to be ended with `END` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
update listings
set price = CASE WHEN (listings.price IS NOT NULL) THEN (price * 
(((100+(select price_change from zips where zips.zipcode=listings.zip))/100)))
where zip in (select zipcode from zips where city = 'Sacramento')
```

remove ; try again